# Want to enumerate Outlook folders

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, outlook

I'm looking for some code (C# or VB.NET preferred) to iterate through all folders in an Outlook mailbox and return the names of those folders.  I'm not looking to pop up the Outlook folder dialog, but rather to return the folder names in a given mailbox from outside Outlook.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually quite easy using [VSTO](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/) (Visual Studio Tools for Office).  First Use VSTO to create an Outlook 2007 add in.  Here is some of my experimental code that does this.

```
   private void RecurseThroughFolders(Outlook.Folder theRootFolder, int depth)
    {
        if ( theRootFolder.DefaultItemType != Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem ) {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", theRootFolder.FolderPath);

        foreach( Object item in theRootFolder.Items ) {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof( Outlook.MailItem )) {
                Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
                if (mi.Categories.Length > 0) {
                    WriteLinePrefix(depth);
                    Console.WriteLine("  $ {0}", mi.Categories);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in theRootFolder.Folders) {
            RecurseThroughFolders(folder, depth + 1);
        }
    }

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();

    Console.WriteLine("Default Profile = {0}", olApp.DefaultProfileName);

    Console.WriteLine("Default Store = {0}", olApp.Session.DefaultStore.DisplayName);

    selectExplorers = this.Application.Explorers;
    selectExplorers.NewExplorer += new Outlook.ExplorersEvents_NewExplorerEventHandler( newExplorer_Event );

    Outlook.Folder theRootFolder  = (Outlook.Folder) olApp.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder();
    RecurseThroughFolders( theRootFolder, 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I prefer a more LINQ friendly approach:

```
private IEnumerable<MAPIFolder> GetAllFolders(Folders folders)
{
    foreach (MAPIFolder f in folders) {
        yield return f;
        foreach (var subfolder in GetAllFolders(f.Folders)) {
            yield return subfolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can peruse the folders any way like. For example:

```
private IEnumerable<MailItem> GetAllEmail(NameSpace ns)
{
    foreach (var f in GetAllFolders(ns.Folders)) {
        if (f == DELETE_FOLDER) continue;
        if (f.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olMailItem) {
            // Party!
        }
    }
}
```