# Get Outlook folder details using LINQ

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I wanted to get Outlook folder details(User Created Outlook Folder Names) using Linq query,There's no any error but expected result not achieved,

[Some example in this site but it doen't get my expected results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861370/want-to-enumerate-outlook-folders)

Here is my code.

```
private IEnumerable<MAPIFolder> GetAllFolders(Folders folders)
{
foreach (MAPIFolder f in folders) {
    yield return f;
    foreach (var subfolder in GetAllFolders(f.Folders)) {
        yield return subfolder;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my button click event,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp  = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace)oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); 

      foreach (var f in GetAllFolders(ns.Folders)) {
    //if (f == DELETE_FOLDER) continue;
    if (f.DefaultItemType == OlItemType.olMailItem) {
       string ff = f.Name;//here i tried to get folder name,but it doen't return foldernames

    }
}

}
```

I wanted to get User Created Folder names..
this is my first Outlook AddIn,If you can provide answer with explanation.it's help me..

Comment: First, you aren't using LINQ and may want to read up more on LINQ. Second, how are you setting up `ns`, maybe that is the problem. I do not see anything otherwise.

Comment: @JustinPihony I just update the coding,I missed that part in previous coding.still same result.

Comment: @JustinPihony I created 3 folders and i wanted to get that folder list.I have no previleges to attach image here.. please see this link > http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=sff5hz&s=6

Comment: You are not getting them at all? I just tested this and it works for me

Comment: @JustinPihony did you get folder names ?

Comment: Yes, maybe remove the check for itemtype just for a check to see what the total set of data is

Comment: I answered your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825647/get-list-of-all-outlook-custom-folders#comment20791234_14825647. Not sure why you wanted to start another thread.