# How to iterate through every mail item in every folder, Outlook Add-in 2010

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin

This is what I've got so far, (not working)

```
private void ScanAllMailItems()
{
    Outlook.Folders folders = _outlookNameSpace.Folders;
    foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in folders)
    {
        foreach (Outlook.MailItem m in folder.Items)
        {
            ScanMailBody(m);
        }
    }
}
```

There is no exception, it seems folder.items is always empty. 
The outlook mailbox itself has 10 folders each with between 20-300 mail

Comment: Is there an exception, can you explain what exactly is happening?

Comment: There is no exception, it seems folder.items is always empty.

Comment: From memory, I don't think NameSpace.Folders is the correct way to get the root folder of your mailbox. Maybe have a look here and try as suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861370/want-to-enumerate-outlook-folders

Comment: Are you getting correct data in 'folders' variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved like this , thanks for the link Simon.

```
    private void ScanAllMailItems()
    {
        var theRootFolder = (Outlook.Folder)_outlookNameSpace.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder();
        RecurseThroughFolders(theRootFolder, 0);
    }

    private void RecurseThroughFolders(Outlook.Folder theRootFolder, int depth)
    {
        if (theRootFolder.DefaultItemType != Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
            return;

        foreach (object item in theRootFolder.Items)
        {
            var mailItem = item as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                var mi = mailItem;
                ScanMailBody(mi);
            }
        }

        foreach (Outlook.Folder folder in theRootFolder.Folders)
        {
            RecurseThroughFolders(folder, depth + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The check for != Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem is a nice addition to the MSDN example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184607.aspx